# Appending a string to a list using if statment

Tags: python

I would like to create a function, named `run`, that accepts a list as an argument.

Comment: What did you tried already?

Comment: I tried using an if statement with this operation if (num%==0): num.append("slap"). However, I cant seem to get the right answer.

Comment: Please update your question with this code that doesn't work to show your work so far.

Answer (score 1):

`append` always puts the new item on the end; if you want to modify the original list, use `insert`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
...     if a[i] % 3 == 0:
...         a.insert(i + 1, "slap!")
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 'slap!', 4, 5, 6, 'slap!']
```

Note that when you `insert` an item, all the *following* items will have their indices increased by one.  Iterating over the list in reverse order, and always inserting in the section of the list you've already seen, is one way to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always append your element in a resulting list, then you check if the current element is a multiple of 3 (or any other number) with a simple check.

```py
def run(sequence: list, word: str = "slap!", modulo_num: int = 3):
   result_seq = []

   for elem in sequence:
      result_seq.append(elem)
      if elem % modulo_num == 0:
         result_seq.append(word)

   return result_seq

SEQUENCE = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = run(SEQUENCE)
print(result)  # [1, 2, 3, 'slap!', 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
from typing import Any, Iterable

data = [*range(1, 20)]
INJECT = "slap!"
POSITION = 3


def run(n: Iterable[int]) -> Iterable[Any]:
    return [
        *chain.from_iterable(
            [v] if i % POSITION else [v, INJECT] for i, v in enumerate(n, start=1)
        )
    ]


result = run(data)
print(result)
```

#### output

```
[1, 2, 3, 'slap!', 4, 5, 6, 'slap!', 7, 8, 9, 'slap!', 10, 11, 12, 'slap!', 13, 14, 15, 'slap!', 16, 17, 18, 'slap!', 19]
```